# How many asynchronous (not multi-threaded) operations are started at once? Is this configurable?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

1. If I call for example `WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync()` 100 times how many of the Tasks are actually parallelly processed?
2. Can I configure it or I need to maintain their number using `List<Task>` and `Task.WaitAny()`?
3. Is there an easy way to see their number in the debugger?
4. What are the best practices in situations like this(processing large number of async tasks)?

*Note: I'm not using Task.Run() so no additional threads are started (as far as I know)*

Comment: `Task.Run` uses the thread pool, so your tasks will run multi-threaded.

Comment: The general form of your question is not answerable, however WebClient specifically has some rate limiting stuff in it. Do you you only care about WebClient or do you want an general answer for any kind of awaitable operation.

Comment: @Scott, I have similar situation like the one described. I don't really use WebClient. The reason I'm posting this question is that if a large number of operations are started at the same time:
- I may cause some scalability issues server-side
- It will be ineffective client-side

Comment: @f0rt seeing your clarification I find myself unable to improve the answer because this is too broad. What specifically is the scenario that we are talking about? Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The degree of parallelism is controlled by the `ServicePoint` infrastructure which I don't fully understand. The default limit is `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`. This is what everybody uses. I have never seen someone use `ServicePoint`.

I recommend disabling the limit and implementing the limiting yourself. Using one global limit for the entire AppDomain doesn't make sense to me. It's also hidden and undocumented to rely on `DefaultConnectionLimit`. Further, `DefaultConnectionLimit` defaults to very different default values depending on the environment (2 vs. int.MaxValue!).

(4) There is [code floating around](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) that allows you to process a sequence of items asynchronously with a certain degree of parallelism. This is the way to go. Controlled parallelism, async and streaming processing with constant memory usage.

Comment: The OP clarified in a comment that he does not really care about WebClient and was looking for a more general form answer.